# Disallow Whitespace Regex

Tags: regex, special-characters, whitespace

I have a regex that does not allow some Special Characters.

```
^[^<>`~!/@\#}$%:;)(_^{&*=|'+]+$
```

Now I want to know how can I modify it to disallow spaces. I tried the following but doesn't work

```
`^\S[^<>`~!/@\#}$%:;)(_^{&*=|'+]+$`
```

Comment: You can add a space into your regex - `^[^<>\`~!/@\#}$%:;)(_^{&*=|'+ ]+$` (or `\s` if you need to disallow all whitespace - `^[^<>\`~!/@\#}$%:;)(_^{&*=|'+\s]+$`)

Comment: Works! could you pls the question so I can Mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disallow any whitespace in the string, add `\s` to your character class:

```
^[^<>`~!/@\#}$%:;)(_^{&*=|'+\s]+$
                            ^^
```

The pattern will now match:

- `^` - a string start
- `[^<>`~!/@#}$%:;)(_^{&*=|'+\s]+`- 1 or more  (due to`+`at the end) characters *other than those* (as it is a negated character class due to`[^...]` notation) defined in the character class
- `$` -  end of string.